# How to convert dataframe to list of lists?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a dataset that looks like a sentiment dictionary.

Say the data is like following:

```
sentiment <-read.table(header=TRUE,text='
term score
awesome    3
good    0
interesting    2
power    1
bad    -1 
horrible    -2
worst    -3'    )
```

I want to convert this data into a list of lists by `score`. Something like following (list names can be different):

```
 $pos3
 [1] awesome
 $pos2
 [1] interesting
 $pos1
 [1] power
 $zero
 [1] good
 $neg1
 [1] bad
 $neg2
 [1] horrible
 $neg3
 [1] worst
```

Other solutions suggested to use `dlply`:

```
 dlply(sentiment, .(score), c)
```

But this produces `score` lists that I don't want. So I ended up using a dumb code like following:

```
 list(neg3=sentiment$term[sentiment$score==-3],neg2=sentiment$term[sentiment$score==-2],
 neg1=sentiment$term[sentiment$score==-1],zero=sentiment$term[sentiment$score==0],
 pos1=sentiment$term[sentiment$score==1], pos2=sentiment$term[sentiment$score==2],
 pos3=sentiment$term[sentiment$score==3])
```

But I wonder if there is a better way to do this.

How can I convert a dataframe to a list of lists without producing lists that I don't want?

Comment: Your data are in a good format for all the practical purposes I can imagine. Are you sure you want to change them? However, you can try with `as.list(setNames(as.character(sentiment$term),sentiment$score))`.

Comment: @nicola Yes, it is in a good format. But there is a package that requires a list format. By the way, your code works when I have only one term per each score. However, when there are multiple terms per score, these terms do not build up under the same score. If I have awesome and perfect under 3, then it does not look like `$'3' [1] awesome perfect`. It looks like `$'3' [1] awesome $'3' [1] perfect`

Comment: So try `split(as.character(sentiment$term),sentiment$score)`. If that doesn't work, edit your OP and state your desired output that handles this case.

Comment: @nicola It works perfect! Thanks!!

Comment: @nicola post as an answer?